# Is there a good standalone GTK# GUI Designer?

Tags: gtk#, gui-designer

I'm looking for a good GUI Designer for GTK#. I know there's Stetic, but it seems to be an inseparable part of MonoDevelop. I don't want to use MonoDevelop, I want to use my editor of choice. Is there any decent standalone GTK# GUI Designer?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/), and load it's generated XML files in C#

Comment: This works great, thanks a bunch!
The following tutorial explains the basics quite well: http://codefez.com/mono-net-gtk-sharp-and-glade/